# Java enum with multiple parameter

Tags: java, enums

I was wondering what would be the way to store multiple values in enum class?

I tried

```
public enum name { 
  James(1,2,3)
  Taylor(2,3,4)
  Mary(5,6,7);
}
```

but this throws me an error.

Comment: FYI, enum names should follow the usual class naming conventions. E.g., `EnumName`.

Comment: sorry if this seems rude but https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: I agree with giorgia: step one is to do research. Trying to invent your own syntax is most often an inefficient approach to programming.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding this, an enum acts just like a normal class: you will need a constructor.

```
private Name(int a, int b, int c) {
    // Define some fields and store a b and c into them
}
```

Notice that within the class body, the enum constants must be defined first, and then the optional fields, constructors and methods:

```
enum Name {
    ENUM_CONSTANT_1, ENUM_CONSTANT_2;

    int field;

    Name() { ... }

    public void someMethod() { ... }

}
```

---

*Note: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: class names (including enum names) always start with uppercase.*

Answer (score 3):

Commas must be between all declared enum instances.

Like any constructor call, the arguments must match a constructor signature.  Declare a constructor to accept three parameters.  You'll probably want to assign them to fields and you may want to provide getters.

```
public enum Name { 
    James(1,2,3),
    Taylor(2,3,4),
    Mary(5,6,7);

    private int a, b, c;

    Name(int a, int b, int c) {
        // Assign to instance variables here
    }
    // Provide getter methods here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `name` constructor. It needs to take at least three ints. It could be variadic. Like,

```
public enum name {
    James(1, 2, 3), Taylor(2, 3, 4), Mary(5, 6, 7);
    int[] arr;
    private name(int... arr) {
        this.arr = arr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test{

 enum EnumName{

    James(1,2,3),
    Taylor(2,3,4),
    Mary(5,6,7);

    private int a,b,c;

    EnumName(int a,int b,int c){
       this.a=a;
       this.b=b;
       this.c=c;
    }
 }

 public static void main(String []args){
    EnumName n = EnumName.James; 
    System.out.println(n.a);
 }
```

}